# Definite negative functions and length functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, c-star-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\ND{ND}$I am reading E. Bedos paper on heat properties for groups.

Let's denote, for a group G, $$\ND^+_0(G) := \{d : G \to [0,+\infty[\; : \;d \text{ is negative definite and }d(e) = 0\}.$$

I want to show that length functions belong to $\ND^+_0(G)$.

So I take $d \in \ND^+_0(G)$,

I am struggling with the step consisting in showing that : $$\sqrt{d(gh)} \leq \sqrt{d(g)} + \sqrt{d(h)}$$ for every $(g,h) \in G$.

Comment: You seem to try to prove that every square root of ND function is a length function, which is correct. (But of course not every length function is ND.)

Answer (score 1):

In the cited paper the authors refer to the book *Harmonic Analysis on Semigroups* by Berg, Christensen and Ressel. The proof given there is quite standard, I would say, and short enough to reproduce it here:

First note that the kernel $K(g,h)=\frac 1 2(d(g)+d(h)-d(g^{-1}h))$ is positive (semi-) definite if $d\in\mathrm{ND}^0_+(G)$ by a direct computation. As a side note, the quantity $K(g,h)$ is nothing but the Gromov product $(g,h)_e$ with respect to the metric $\rho(g,h)=d(g^{-1}h)$.

In other words, the matrix $[K(g,h)]_{g,h}$ is positive semidefinite. In particular, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
\frac 1 4 \lvert d(g)+d(h)-d(gh)\rvert=\lvert K(g,h)\rvert\leq \sqrt{K(g,g)}\sqrt{K(h,h)}=\sqrt{d(g)}\sqrt{d(h)}.
$$
Thus $d(gh)\leq (\sqrt{d(g)}+\sqrt{d(h)})^2$, and the claimed inequality follows.